# I am new to MVC 5, I want to bind dropdownlistfor from master table and entityframework6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC 5, I want to bind dropdownlistfor from master table and entityframework6. I am creating Building page and on that page I want to bind list of branches under which building will come.
To fetch data I am using EntityFramework 6.

Comment: You should make an attempt and share where you are having trouble. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] to explain the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

In the Controller Page:

```
private DBEntities db = new DBEntities();

    public ActionResult Load()
    {
        ViewBag.PlusOrMinus1 = new SelectList(db.t_CartesianSymbol, "CartId", "CartesianSymbol");
        return View();
    }
```

And in the View Page:

```
<div class="row poc-row-alert">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PlusOrMinus1, "Operator 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.DropDownList("PlusOrMinus1", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlusOrMinus1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please, do the needful changes.